# Dependency Injection of datasource and jdbctemplate?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, jdbctemplate

I am very new to webapp development in general and Spring framework in particular. I am following this [Spring JDBC Transactions tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/) But instead of accessing the db service from only one class, I wish to access it from multiple classes.

In the tutorial the service is defined like this

```
public class BookingService {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional
    public void book(String... persons) {
        for (String person : persons) {
            System.out.println("Booking " + person + " in a seat...");
            jdbcTemplate.update("insert into BOOKINGS(FIRST_NAME) values (?)", person);
        }
    };

    public List<String> findAllBookings() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("select FIRST_NAME from BOOKINGS", new RowMapper<String>()     
            @Override
            public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                return rs.getString("FIRST_NAME");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

These are the Beans

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

@Bean
BookingService bookingService() {
    return new BookingService();
}

@Bean
DataSource dataSource() {
    return new SimpleDriverDataSource() {{
        setDriverClass(org.h2.Driver.class);
        setUsername("sa");
        setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem");
        setPassword("");
    }};
}

@Bean
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    System.out.println("Creating tables");
    jdbcTemplate.execute("drop table BOOKINGS if exists");
    jdbcTemplate.execute("create table BOOKINGS(" +
            "ID serial, FIRST_NAME varchar(5) NOT NULL)");
    return jdbcTemplate;
}
```

They instantiated the service in only the Application class and did all the transactions there

```
ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
BookingService bookingService = ctx.getBean(BookingService.class);

//bookingService.doStuff()
```

In my test project, I copied the same Bean definitions but I performed the transactions in multiple classes.

```
public class foo {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
    BookingService bookingService = ctx.getBean(BookingService.class);
    bookingService.book(...);
    // some other stuff
}

public class bar {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
    BookingService bookingService = ctx.getBean(BookingService.class);
    bookingService.findAllBookings(...);
    // some other stuff
}
```

It seems that when I perform all transactions in one class only (for example, *book* and *find* in foo class) it performs as expected. But when I try to separate them into multiple classes it doesn't behave as expected. If I perform the *book* in foo, I cannot *find* in bar. What concept am I missing? Am I instantiating multiple instances of the datasource and jdbctemplate because I instantiated the service multiple times. But I thought Spring handles the injection? And since there is only one physical database then there would only be one instance of datasource and jdbctemplate. What concept did I misunderstood? Please help and point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: There is no injection here. YOu are just constructing everything again and get fresh copies. You should inject the `BookingService` into your `foo` and `bar` classes. You should never reconstruct the applicationcontext yourself, you must construct it once and only to wire together your application.

Comment: I followed the pattern in the tutorial. I will try to do your suggestion in my project and report it here. Tnx.

Comment: I don't see any reference to using Spring MVC in the question. I'd recommend removing the spring-mvc tag

Comment: I totally misunderstood the Application context. I was following the tutorial. I thought that the context was defined in the Spring tutorial to get access to the Bean. So if I am going to access the same Beans in my classes, I should define the contexts again. Long ways to go before I can get complete understanding of these concepts.

Comment: Removed it SteveD. I was actually doing a Spring MVC project. I was mixing and matching several Spring tutorials. And I got stuck with the JDBC part.

Answer (score -1):

You need to inject your dependencies, for example:

```
public class Foo {

    @Autowired
    private BookingService bookingService;

    public doStuff() {
        bookingService.book(...);
        // some other stuff
    }
}
```